# Postgresql Completing date_trunc(ts,'hour') with missing values

Tags: postgresql, datetime

I have a table with ts values and an int for how many times an event occurs in that ts.
The problem is that if there is no event in a ts, this ts is not recorded in the DB, like the following example:

```
ts                 |  n
-------------------------
2014-09-26 01:00:00|  10
2014-09-26 03:00:00|  12
2014-09-26 05:00:00|  1
2014-09-26 06:00:00|  2
2014-09-26 07:00:00|  4
2014-09-26 08:00:00|  3
```

What I need to do is perform a query that can complete all the missing ts values (trun at hour) in the interval to get something like this:

```
ts                 |  n
-------------------------
2014-09-26 01:00:00|  10
2014-09-26 02:00:00|  0
2014-09-26 03:00:00|  12
2014-09-26 04:00:00|  0
2014-09-26 05:00:00|  1
2014-09-26 06:00:00|  2
2014-09-26 07:00:00|  4
2014-09-26 08:00:00|  3
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to generate a list of all possible values between the min and max value for ts, and then outer join that against the table:

```
with min_max as (
    select min(date_trunc('hour', ts)) as min_hour,
           max(date_trunc('hour', ts)) as max_hour
    from the_table
)
select s.s, coalesce(t.n, 0)
from generate_series( (select min_hour from min_max), (select max_hour from min_max), interval '1' hour) as s
   left join the_table t on s.s = date_trunc('hour', t.ts)
order by s.s;
```

If this doesn't need to be dynamic, and you can hardcode the start and end date, this looks a lot easier to understand:

```
select s.s, coalesce(t.n, 0)
from generate_series( timestamp '2014-09-26 01:00:00', timestamp '2014-09-26 08:00:00', interval '1' hour) as s
   left join the_table t on s.s = date_trunc('hour', t.ts)
order by s.s;
```

Comment: Is this the only way?? My table has 50 mill records and take upto 2.3 minutes for this query... is there a faster way??